# Как подключать стили в php?

Tags: php, html, css, include, link

Я новичок в php. Создал папку в которой 2 файла - `index.php`(В нём html код) и `menu.php` (В нём, html меню для index.php) Подключал я меню в index.php через include а в menu.php я в теги `<style>` добавил css код для меню. Не знаю как лучше - создать новый файл css и подключить к menu.php через `<link>` или как сделал я? Ещё проблема в том, что когда я подключаю созданный файл media.css к главной странице, ничего не происходит, точнее он не работает, я пробывал просто поменять фон гл. страницы но ничего не получилось. Если кто-то ответит буду очень благодарен.

Comment: «Не знаю как лучше - создать новый файл css и подключить к menu.php через <link> или как сделал я?» — как Вам нравится, так и сделайте. «ничего не происходит, точнее он не работает, я пробывал просто поменять фон гл. страницы но ничего не получилось» — смотрите ошибки в консоли браузера.

Comment: В консоли никаких ошибок нет, я проверил все пути, всё правильно указал, не знаю в чём ошибка...

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос.

Comment: Ответ очевиден: html разметку и css стили не рекомендуется писать в один файл. А фон всей страницы не меняется потому что у вас там только менюшка, и высоты документа в index.php нет.